# Laravel Carbon optional parameter

Tags: php, laravel, api, php-carbon

I have a function which communicates with external API, and would like it to pass in optional parameters as a `Carbon` instance, however API wants a `Y-m-d` format so I've done this:

```
protected function boostsAPIRequest($token, Carbon $dateFrom = null, Carbon $dateTo = null)
{
    try {
        $boosts = $this->httpGetRequest($token,
            $this->apiURL . 'stats/api/v1.0/boosts' . '/?date_from=' . $dateFrom->format('Y-m-d') . '&date_to=' . $dateTo->format('Y-m-d'));
        //session()->put('boosts', $boosts);
    } catch (ClientException $e) {
        $this->errorHandling($e);
    }
    return $boosts ?? null;
}
```

this gives me an error saying

```
Call to a member function format() on null
```

Is there a way to keep it empty if no parameter was passed in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$dateFrom->format('Y-m-d') . '&date_to=' . $dateTo->format('Y-m-d')
```

use should use:

```
($dateFrom ? $dateFrom->format('Y-m-d') : '') . '&date_to=' . ($dateTo ? $dateTo->format('Y-m-d') : '')
```

this is because you cannot run `format` method on non-object (null in this case)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply allow string value to be passed into the function, the use `parse()` method of Carbon like so:

```
protected function boostsAPIRequest($token, $dateFrom = null, $dateTo = null) {
    $dateFrom = Carbon::parse($dateFrom);
   //the same with $dateTo
}
```

**Beware** Carbon knows how to resolve null value to the `now` date time in case it receives null since null is even the default value for most of the functions the creates an instance of Carbon.